# Data loaded from DB table into input text, chopped off text by space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

data loaded from DB table into input text (bootstrap3) chopped off text by space

I want to view the result as "Google Company Inc., " But I can only see
"Google"

Comment: This is my code     <input id="agencyName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=@item.Name1 readonly/>

Comment: when I inspect it , <input id="agencyName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Google" Company readonly="">   Can someone help?

Comment: I ended up using textarea instead of input. Her is my sample usage     <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="alladdress">